# How to get stripe_card_token to save when a new order is created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

This is the response I'm generating:

```
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"C/1Fmc4iEAiRGXwTcQNcDdX3j81KyhMHnfNcuYC/p1Y=", "order"=>{"video_id"=>"99", "member_id"=>"36", "price"=>"1000", "stripe_card_token"=>"tok_2mYQqbzBgt1EYy"}}
Completed 404 Not Found in 22ms

ActionController::RoutingError - No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"orders", :id=>#<Order id: nil, video_id: 99, member_id: 36, stripe_card_token: nil, price: 1000, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>}:
```

Basically all the correct attributes are being generated when a new order is created, but for some reason the stripe_card_token isn't being passed to the params.

This is my Order model:

```
  attr_accessible :price, :stripe_card_token, :member_id, :video_id

  belongs_to :video
  belongs_to :member

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :video
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :member

    validates :member_id, presence: true
    validates :video_id, presence: true
    validates :price, presence: true

  attr_accessor :stripe_card_token


   def save_with_stripe
    if valid?
      @charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
        amount: price,
        currency: "gbp",
        card: stripe_card_token,
        description: "something"
      )

      save!
    end
  rescue
    errors.add :base, "There was a problem with Stripe"
  end
```

This is my orders controller:

```
  def new
    @order = Order.new(:member_id => @member.id, :video_id => @video.id, :price => @video.price)    
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    if @order.save_with_stripe
      flash[:success] = "Enjoy the video!"
      redirect_to order_path(@order)
    else
      render partial: 'orders/buynow'
    end
  end

  def show
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end
```

And my form:

```
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
    <% if @order.errors.any? %>
      <div class="error_messages">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@order.errors.count, "error") %> stopped your card from being charged:</h2>
        <ul>
        <% @order.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :video_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :member_id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :price %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

    <% if current_user.stripe_customer_token.present? %>
      Credit card has been provided.
    <% else %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :name, "Name on card" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :name, nil, name: nil %>
      </div>    
      <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
        <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"} %>
        <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <div id="stripe_error">
      <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Buy Now" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

And my coffeescript:

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  order.setupForm()

order =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_order').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        order.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, order.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#order_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#new_order')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

Can you help me understand what I'm going wrong?

EDIT 1:

This is the new response generated in my development logs now I fixed the issue with trying to pass an undefinfed local variable of 'email' into the 'description' key.

```
Started POST "/orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-19 14:45:22 +0100
Processing by OrdersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"C/1Fmc4iEAiRGXwTcQNcDdX3j81KyhMHnfNcuYC/p1Y=", "order"=>{"video_id"=>"99", "member_id"=>"36", "price"=>"1000", "stripe_card_token"=>"tok_2mZBErSMVjAa3F"}}
   (1.9ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (2.4ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("created_at", "member_id", "price", "stripe_card_token", "updated_at", "video_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Sat, 19 Oct 2013 13:45:24 UTC +00:00], ["member_id", 36], ["price", 1000], ["stripe_card_token", nil], ["updated_at", Sat, 19 Oct 2013 13:45:24 UTC +00:00], ["video_id", 99]]
   (2.3ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://eqrfqer.xavy.dev/orders/13
```

For some reason the stripe_card_token that is generated in the params isn't being inserted into my Order model.  That's the issue, but I can't understand why?

EDIT 2:

I think maybe the issue was actually me trying to pass the undefined email to 'description'.  Since I changed that, I can see charges are getting passed into my Stripe account.  I don't understand why it looks in the logs as though the stripe_card_token is 'nil' but I assume it must be a security feature?

Anyway, it now appears to be working.

Comment: It looks like it's getting to your `OrdersController#create`, and then it can't find a route that matches orders show-- so I think it *is* getting to the `redirect_to order_path(@order)` in your `OrdersController#create`. Is this a production log? Can you do this in development (or turn on database logs in production) and see if the `Order` is being created in the database? What about adding some logging statements in the `create` action to see what the attributes of your order are at various points? I'd also recommend resolving the no route error before worrying about the stripe_card_token.

Comment: The route is fine.  There was an issue with my method 'save_with_stripe' I just noticed, I was trying to pass in a local variable 'email' to 'description'  when it isn't defined in the model.  But even with that changed, the big issue is that while the 'stripe_card_token' is being generated in the params, it isn't being passed into the Order model when it is created.  And I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

by writing this line:

```
attr_accessor :stripe_card_token
```

you are killing the rails functionality for setting the `stripe_card_token`

if it is a column in your database, remove it!